# Zend Framework wildcard subdomain route for variable domains

Tags: zend-framework, routes, dns, wildcard

I am busy with developing a engine with Zend Framework who makes it able to run
a couple of my websites with (all the same kind).

Now I work with a wildcard subdomain for these websites, my problem is I can't figure out how I write a route in my application.ini with also the 'head' domain as a variable.

what I need to route:
domain 1: *.site1.com
domain 2: *.site2.com (etc.)

What I would like to have

```
routes.subdomain.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
routes.subdomain.route = ":subdomain.:domain"
routes.subdomain.defaults.module = "default"
routes.subdomain.chains.index.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
routes.subdomain.chains.index.route = ":controller/:action/"
routes.subdomain.chains.index.defaults.controller = "data"
routes.subdomain.chains.index.defaults.action = "index"
```

Thanks in advance!

Nick

Comment: It will be helpful if you write whether your code does not work at all, or works incorrectly (how?) and what kind of help you actually expect. You can add a regular-expression-based requirement to your rule: `routes.subdomain.domain.reqs = [regexp here]` to try and enforce proper recognition of your main domains and thus splitting the URI in the desired position so that the subdomains are recognized. I'm not 100% sure this will work out of the box, but it sure is worth giving a try.

Comment: It doesn't work how I want at all, just if I write the domain hard in the ini code. I need just to know how to make ':domain' variable